# Sort Dates when Dates are missing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a series of start and end dates that I am trying to sort.  I have instances where there are two start dates without a missing end date that would be between the two start dates.  How can I create a sort that will reflect this and leave the cell between the two dates blank?

I have been able to do a simple bubble sort. but it fills in where the missing date should be.

Given the four dates below I want the vb coding to leave Hire Date 2 blank

```
HIRE DT1   TERM DT1   HIRE DT2   TERM DT2   HIRE DT3
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
04/01/2000 12/01/2005 (Blank)    09/01/2008 08/01/2010
```

Currently my result shows the correct order for HIRE and TERM separately, but not as it should be above.

```
HIRE DT1   TERM DT1   HIRE DT2   TERM DT2   HIRE DT3
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
04/01/2000 12/01/2005 08/01/2010 09/01/2008 (Blank)
```

Comment: How is your last example sorted? How can it be that `2010` comes before `2008`? Please clarify! • The only way to solve this wouy be to sort `DT1` first, then sort `DT2` and then sort `DT3` otherwise it will always mix it up.

Comment: There are actually two sorts.  One for the hire dates and the other for the term dates.  So the update puts the hire dates in order but when combined with the term dates it puts the hire date of 2010 before the term date of 2008.  the result I want is in the first example.

Comment: Well then we need an example of your source data. How does it look like **before** you sort?